# source bash array from file - save changed array to source

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I've got a sourced file from where I'm using an array. I work with this array and add one new value to it like this:

```
read ${arrayname}[3] <<<"$ip"
```

Arrayname and ip are variables. I want to save the array with the added IP to the source file.
In the sourced file I declared the array this way:

```
declare -a array0  
array0=(value1 value2 value3)
```

The IP should be at [3], so behind the given values.

Comment: You can use: `declare -p "$arrayname" >> file`. This will append the declaration of your array to the file you're sourcing. Then, when you source it back, the last declaration will take effect. This will very likely clutter your file quickly if used often. Otherwise you need to have some markers in your file, and insert the output of `declare -p "$arrayname"` using these markers.

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to have a separate file, say `file_ip` that you source from your main file, and you just update this file with: `declare -p "$arrayname" > file_ip`.

Comment: To use a second file is a good idea - but not usable in the context of my stuff there :)
when i user    `declare -p..`    then there appears a new    `declare -a array0='([0]=value1 ..... with [3]"theipaddress")`    at the end of the file. is there a way to set the ip directly in the existing code where I say    `array0=(value1 value2 value3)`    ?

Comment: Yes there is, but it involves putting some markers in the source file and editing the file (e.g., with `sed` or `ed`, or maybe Bash too) to remove everything between the markers and put the output of `declare -p` instead. It's not the most elegant method.

Comment: I guess, then it's the best thing to stay with `declare -p`. That will also finally work. Thanks! :)

Comment: one last problem.. the `declare -p` creates a blank line before the command. How can i avoi that? Blank lines in bash aren't that cool..

Comment: What do you mean? `declare -p` doesn't create anything... if you have another question, try to understand it, make a minimal working example, and post it as a new question.

Comment: Shortly: `declare -p "$arrayname" >> file` creates a new line in the file with that content: `declare -a array0='([0]="value1" [1]="value2" [2]="value3" [3]="192.168.bla.bla")' `

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point.

Comment: But there is a empty line created before this line.

Comment: No. Probably the empty line already existed before in the file. Try this: `a=( one two three ); declare -p a >> test; declare -p a >> test; declare -p a >> test; declare -p a >> test`. You'll see that `declare` doesn't insert an empty line before (look at the file `test`).

Comment: Okey.. my mistake, sorry.